# how can i get "one" OBJECT from "many" OBJECT in ManyToOne relationship? please help me?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

this is my java code :three entity including `CompanyTypeRelation ,CompanyType,Department`

```
public class CompanyTypeRelation  implements java.io.Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 4227115995926533087L;
   // Fields    

    private long id;
    private CompanyType companyType;
    private Department department;
    private long operator;
    private String operateTime;
    // the relationship
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="company_type_id", nullable=false)

    public CompanyType getCompanyType() {
       return this.companyType;
    }

    public void setCompanyType(CompanyType companyType) {
      this.companyType = companyType;
    }
        // the relationship
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id", nullable=false)

    public Department getDepartment() {
       return this.department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
    }
    ..............
    other code:
}
```

this is my query sql :

```
SELECT c 
FROM com.hna.dt.orm.CompanyTypeRelation c 
LEFT JOIN c.companyType ct LEFT JOIN c.department cd
```

can I  get `departmentName` from `Department` by the sql above?

Comment: This is not SQL, but HQL. And it doesn't make much sense. What exactly do you want to achieve? What is the output you would like from the query?

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the departmentName is in the department table, just add cd.name (or whatever the column name is) to your select list.

Comment: thanks for answer.  departmentName is in the department table; but when i query the sql ,i can get infomation about department and companyType, could you help me?